# A stable very low-voltage reference generator (a very low-voltage LDO design idea)

Tags: circuit-design, analog, voltage-regulator, ldo, low-voltage

Essentially, I have a voltage which varies between 0.15 VDC to 0.25 VDC, and this feeds into a system whose output is varying because of this variation at the input side. This is summarized in the figure below:

[image]

There has been a requirement of coming up with a method to stabilize this varying low voltage at the input side before feeding it to V_ref. Essentially, I am looking for a LDO type of functionality, but in very low voltage regimes. The system I am looking for is something like this:

[image]

The designed circuit somehow reduces the variations in input voltage to a range of 100 μV (ignore the ). Additionally, the designed circuit for generating Vx must have good noise and temperature performance (say over range of -40°C to +80°C).

Comment: You can't step up a voltage with an LDO... You need a switchmode regulator. This is going to be more than just difficult. Also, are you sure about your 2µV requirement? Solder joints alone generate more voltage than that due to thermoelectric effects.

Comment: I have corrected the voltage requirement in question to 100µV.

Comment: That's more realistic. What output current do you require?

Comment: What power supply rails do you have available?

Comment: Look up circuit design using mosfets in the sub-threshold region. This is the lowest voltage technology.

Answer (score 1):

This is a multi-step approach.

You need something like an energy harvesting boost converter (e.g. [MAX17710](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max17710.pdf)) to boost this voltage up to some intermediate voltage, e.g. 1.75V. Then you can use a ultra stable voltage reference IC, e.g. the [LTC6655](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc6655-6655ln.pdf) with 1.25V fixed output voltage (0.5V dropout). This output voltage can then be divided with a precision voltage divider back to 0.2V.

One problem that you might face is that your original source (0.15V to 0.25V) must deliver quite some current to be able to drive the voltage reference IC (LTC6655 needs 7mA) at the intermediate voltage.